# Uncaught ReferenceError: vec2 is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I keep getting the following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: vec2 is not defined
    at initVars (triangle.html:57)
    at init (triangle.html:28)"
I know vec2 is defining a two-dimensional vector so I am not sure why it says its not defined. Any help would be apperciated, thank you!

My code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Twisted Triangle Assignment 1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="600" height="600">
    Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
    </canvas>

    <script language= "JavaScript">
        "use strict";
        var points = []; //empty array, we put the points here as we do the subdivision
        var tessellationGrade;
        var angle;
        var renderType;
        var vertices;
        var radios;

        window.onload = function init()
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );

            var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
            //var gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
            if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

            initVars();
            initUI();

            //tessellation
            tessellation(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2], tessellationGrade);

            //  Configure WebGL
            gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
            gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

            //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
            var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
            gl.useProgram( program );

            // Load the data into the GPU
            var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferId );
            gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );


            // Associate out shader variables with our data buffer
            var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
            gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

            render();
        };

        function initVars(){
            vertices = [
                vec2 (-0.61,-0.35), // left-down corner
                vec2( 0,  0.7),  // center-up corner
                vec2 ( 0.61, -0.35) // right-down corner
            ]; 

            // Twist Angle
            var angleValue = document.getElementById("slider-angle").value;
            angle = angleValue * Math.PI / 180;


            //Render Type
            radios = document.getElementsByName('render-type');
            for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
                if (radios[i].checked) {
                    renderType = radios[i].value;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Tessellation Grade
            tessellationGrade = document.getElementById("slider-tessellation").value;


        }

        function initUI(){

            // Twist UI
            document.getElementById("slider-angle").addEventListener("input", function(e){
                    angle = this.value * Math.PI / 180;
                    rerender();
            }, false);

            // Render Type UI
            for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
               radios[i].onclick = function() {
                    renderType = this.value;
                    rerender();
                };
            }

            // Tessellation Grade UI
            document.getElementById("slider-tessellation").addEventListener("input", function(e){
                    tessellationGrade = this.value;
                    rerender();
            }, false);


        }

        function twist(vector){
            var x = vector[0],
                y = vector[1],
                d = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                sinAngle = Math.sin(d * angle),
                cosAngle = Math.cos(d * angle);

                /*
                    x' = x cos(d0) - y sin(d0)
                    y' = x sin(d0) + y cos(d0)

                */

                return [x * cosAngle - y * sinAngle, x * sinAngle + y * cosAngle];
        }

        function triangle (a, b, c){

            a = twist(a), b = twist(b), c = twist(c);

            if(renderType=="TRIANGLES"){
                points.push(a, b, c);
            } else {
                points.push(a, b);
                points.push(b, c);
                points.push(a, c);
            }
        }

        function tessellation(a, b, c, count){

            if(count===0){
                //when we are at the end of the recursion we push 
                //the triangles to the array
                triangle(a,b,c);


            } else {
                //bisect the sides
                var ab = mix( a, b, 0.5 );
                var ac = mix( a, c, 0.5 );
                var bc = mix( b, c, 0.5 );

                --count;

                //new triangles
                tessellation(a, ab, ac, count);
                tessellation(c, ac, bc, count);
                tessellation(b, bc, ab, count);
                tessellation(ac, bc, ab, count);

            }

        }

        function rerender(){
            points = [];
            tessellation(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2], tessellationGrade);
            gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
            render();
        }

        function render() {
            gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
            if(renderType=="TRIANGLES"){
                gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, points.length );
            }
            else {
                gl.drawArrays( gl.LINES, 0, points.length );   
            }
        }
    </script>

    <section>

        <fieldset>
          <legend>Twist angle</legend>
          <input id="slider-angle" name="angle" type="range" min="0" max="360" step="1" value="120" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
              <legend>Tessellation Grade</legend>
              <input id="slider-tessellation" name="tessellation" type="range" min="1" max="6" step="1" value="5" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
              <legend>Render Type</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="render-type" value="LINES" />Lines<br />
                <input type="radio" name="render-type" value="TRIANGLES" checked="checked"/>Triangles<br />
        </fieldset>

    </section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `vec2` is *GLSL* you're writing *JavaScript*

Comment: As others have pointed out, there is no `vec2` in JavaScript. So either you you need to define it yourself, or you're mistaking `vec2` that's part of the GLSL language used in shaders with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

`vec2` seems to be used like a function but I'm unable to find `vec2` function declaration